# Restrict openSSH 6.1p1 logins via LDAP to an IP range

Tags: ssh, ip, ldap, solaris

I have some servers in the DMZ that receive public traffic from an external (public) IPv4 address. This is translated at our gateway to a 172.x.x.x address.

All external clients are using local accounts and are chrooted. They connect via this manner.

Internal accounts coming from our internal addresses are from 10.x.x.x

I would like to restrict openssh to listen to LDAP only from the internal (10.x) network. I would like to configure this within the sshd conf file if possible (no tcpwrappers or iptables).

So,

sshd connections -> 172.x.x.x local auth only
sshd connections -> 10.x.x.x local+ldap auth

Running openssh 6.1p1

Thanks,

Drew.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use pam_access. I don't think you can do this in sshd_config self.

To enable pam_access add the following line to the pam sshd service file. On my system that's /etc/pam.d/sshd.

```
account  required     pam_access.so
```

Then you should put the local users and ldap user in different groups. Let's say group localusers and group ldapusers.

You can now edit access limits in /etc/security/access.conf:

```
# root only from local-network?
+ : root : : 10.0.0.0/8
# users in ldap only access from local network
+ : (ldapusers) : 10.0.0.0/8
# local user only access from 172.x.x.x network
+ : (localusers) : 172.0.0.0/8
# Deny all other users to get access from all sources?
- : ALL : ALL
```

Try to understand the access.conf config first, because you can easily lock-out yourself.